# How do I write a mongoDB query to update an array of objects in a collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, javascript-objects

I have a cart collection that has two fields, userId and products (which is an array of all the products associated with a user). How do I query each of the product in the products array to update its quantity and total price, if a product with the same id is added to the collection?[cart collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM18t.png)

Here's is my code. So when I try to test this using postman, it actually updates a product's quantity and total price, where the id matches, but only once. But this result does not persist in the database, i.e, when I run db.cart.find() on my terminal, I don't see the updates.

````
exports.addCartItem = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const product = req.body.product;
    const userId = req.user._id;

    let cart = await Cart.findOne( {userId} ).exec();
    console.log(cart)
    
    const price = product.price;
    const title = product.title;
    const quantity = product.quantity;
    const totalPrice = product.totalPrice;
    const status = product.status;

    if (cart) {
        const itemIndex = cart.products.findIndex((p) => p.product.toString() === product.product);  
        console.log(itemIndex)
        if(itemIndex > -1) {
            let productItem = cart.products[itemIndex];
            productItem.quantity += quantity;
            productItem.totalPrice = productItem.quantity * price;
            cart.products[itemIndex] = productItem;
        } else {
            cart.products.push(
                { 
                    product: product.product, 
                    title, quantity, price, 
                    status, 
                    totalPrice: quantity * price,
                });  
        }

        res.status(200).json(cart);
    
    } else {
        const newCart = await Cart.create({
            userId,
            products: [
                { 
                    product: product.product, 
                    title, 
                    quantity, 
                    price, 
                    status, 
                    totalPrice: quantity * price 
                }],
        });
        if (!newCart) next(AppError('Product was not created', 400))
        return res.status(201).json({
            status: 'success',
            newCart
        });
    }
});```
````

Comment: `cart.save()` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

To update an array of objects in a MongoDB collection, you can use the $set operator along with the positional operator $ to specify the array element you want to update. Here's how you can modify your code to update the products array in the Cart collection:

```
exports.addCartItem = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
const product = req.body.product;
const userId = req.user._id;

let cart = await Cart.findOne({ userId }).exec();
console.log(cart)

const price = product.price;
const title = product.title;
const quantity = product.quantity;
const totalPrice = product.totalPrice;
const status = product.status;

if (cart) {
    const itemIndex = cart.products.findIndex((p) => p.product.toString() === product.product);
    console.log(itemIndex)
    if (itemIndex > -1) {
        // Update an existing product in the products array
        cart.products[itemIndex].quantity += quantity;
        cart.products[itemIndex].totalPrice = cart.products[itemIndex].quantity * price;
    } else {
        // Add a new product to the products array
        cart.products.push(
            {
                product: product.product,
                title,
                quantity,
                price,
                status,
                totalPrice: quantity * price,
            });
    }

    // Update the cart document in the database
    await cart.save();

    res.status(200).json(cart);

} else {
    // Create a new cart document with the product
    const newCart = await Cart.create({
        userId,
        products: [
            {
                product: product.product,
                title,
                quantity,
                price,
                status,
                totalPrice: quantity * price
            }],
    });

    if (!newCart) next(AppError('Product was not created', 400))

    res.status(201).json({
        status: 'success',
        newCart
    });
}
```

});
In this code, after making changes to the cart.products array, we call await cart.save() to persist the changes to the MongoDB database. This will update the Cart document with the modified products array.